# How can stream camera from iphone/ipad to mac in the same wifi network?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming

I need to achieve something similar with EpocCam application from Appstore but the problem is I don't know from where I can start, what steps must following (I searched over net and what I found it was vague.) Any suggestion in this direction?

Answer (score 0):

From the implementation view point, live streaming can be broken down into the following sub-tasks:

1. Get the stream data while shooting.
2. Parse the stream data.
3. Convert the stream into the format supported by the server.
4. Deliver the data to the server.

There isn't a built-in way to do this. You will need to implement the [**AVCaptureSession**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Simplest implementation would send each captured frame to the server.

Example:

```
// Create input.
AVCaptureDevice *camera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:camera error:nil];

// Create data output.
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

// Create capture session and set input and output.
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[[AVCaptureSession alloc] init] autorelease];
[captureSession addInput:input];
[captureSession addOutput:output];

// Create a preview layer.
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];
previewLayer.frame = view.bounds;
[view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];

// Start capturing the video.
[captureSession startRunning];
```

Delegate's callback:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    // Get captured frame.
    CVImageBufferRef buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
}
```

Also, have a look at: [AV Foundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2)

Comment: @reecon-good advice in my scenario the server is a mac, on mac side I need to build a native application for mac OS who know parse the stream came from iphone/ipad, right?(or I can use a browser?). thanks